# Is it possible to have interaction term in t test?

Tags: t-test, categorical-data, interaction, paired-data

I have data of glucose measurements of 100 patients taken at 2 different time points. Of these, 40 people were taking pioglitazone drug and 60 of them were on placebo. I want to test (1) whether there is change in glucose between the time points and (2) whether the change is different between drugs.

I have done a pairwise t test for my first question. But how do I get as an answer for my second question? What test should I use?

Comment: You're looking for [mixed ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-design_analysis_of_variance).

Comment: But I have only two categories/groups. Is it fine to do ANOVA with 2 groups?

Comment: Please take a look at [Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3466/237901).

Comment: You most probably want a single model that incorporates both *Time* and *Treatment*.  ... Can you confirm that a single individual is measured at both *Time1* and *Time2* ?